# Pandas equivalent of R merge all=TRUE

Tags: python, pandas

apologies if this sounds like a dumb question, I haven't worked on Pandas for a long time.

I've two data frames, Nodes:

[image: Nodes]

Rate Card:

[image: Rate Card]

I want the final output to look like this, total would be 7*10= 70 rows:

[image: OP]

In R, I use the following piece of code to do this:

```
prem_subset = merge(nodes, subset(rate_card, select=c("service", "duration","rate")),all=TRUE)

where I'm only selecting some columns from my original rate_card df
```

I can't find the Pandas equivalent for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC I believe you are looking for pandas [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with option `how=cross`:

```
select_cols = ['service', 'duration', 'rate']
nodes.merge(rate_card[select_cols], how='cross')
```

Comment: Ah, that does it. I knew it would be something basic but I just couldn't find it, my bad. I genuinely felt guilty asking this. Thanks for the simple and quick answer.